# Where to keep my custom PHP files in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a child them in Wordpress by replicating the Parent theme. My child theme sole purpose is to fetch the data from the database i have created.

I have created a connect.php file which will connect to my database whenever i have to retrieve the data or add data to/from database.

for the simple Login form, i added my connect.php file in the action attribute just to check if I am able to connect to my database or not but i think it is not able to fetch or connect to connect.php file.

My form html code :

```
<body>
  <div class="lform">
    <div class="loginbox">
      <img class="avatar" src="">
      <h1>Login Here</h1>`enter code here`
      <form method="POST" action="connect.php">
        <p>Username</p>
        <input name="" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
        <p>Password</p>
        <input name="" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
        <input name="" type="submit" value="Login">
        <a href="#">Lost your password?</a><br>
        <a href="#">Don't have an account?</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <body>
```

connect.php code

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

I have placed the file in the child theme directory where the functions.php file resides.

I have connect.php file and a html form . Could you please tell me what else would be needed or where i have to place my file so that my html form can call it and process it.

Do i have to add it in functions.php file ?

I want to maintain a separate file(connect.php) so that i can call it from anywhere and where ever it is required.

Like connect.php , i will be creating another php files as well like for validations or for some other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Child theme is for the purpose of overwriting the templates and files. Not for the other purposes.

You can add your files at the root folder of wordpress installation.